# How can I make this JS repetitive code shorter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just wrote this piece of code that does the thing it's supposed to do, although it's really messy and pretty repetitive and I'm wondering how can I make it much shorter and concise.

```
if(id==1 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[0])
    }else if(id==1 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[0])
    }
    if(id==2 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[1])
    }else if(id==2 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[1])
    }
    if(id==3 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[2])
    }else if(id==3 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[2])
    }
    if(id==4 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[3])
    }else if(id==4 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[3])
    }
    if(id==5 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[4])
    }else if(id==5 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[4])
    }
    if(id==6 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[5])
    }else if(id==6 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[5])
    }
    if(id==7 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[6])
    }else if(id==7 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[6])
    }
    if(id==8 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[7])
    }else if(id==8 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[7])
    }
    if(id==9 && player == "playerOne"){
      Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[8])
    }else if(id==9 && player =="playerTwo"){
      Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[8])
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `fighters[id - 1]` will take care of all cases, resulting into a single `if else`

Comment: So (assuming there are no more than 2 players)... `Object.assign(player == "playerOne" ? playerOne : playerTwo, fighters[id - 1])`. Job done.

Comment: Note that if the code works, and it's something you've written, and you'd be willing to share more about it, the question *may* be on topic for [codereview.se], but you should check their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure.

Comment: thank you guys! yea I wrote the code I just needed some alternatives to it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming

a) there are no more than two players

b) you don't care that this code handles `id < 1` and `id > 9`

It looks to me like you could reduce this to a single line.

```
Object.assign(player == "playerOne" ? playerOne : playerTwo, fighters[id - 1])
```

Comment: Yea this works perfectly and is definitely prettier than my beginner code haha, thank you kind sir

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumptions in your example, that `id` must be between `1` and `9` and `player` can be anything, but must be `playerOne` or `playerTwo`:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (id == i) {
        if(player == "playerOne"){
            Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[i - 1]);
        } else if (player == "playerTwo") {
            Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but splender's answer was perfect in this case

Comment: splender's answer does not make sure, that `id` is between 1 and 9.

Comment: And besides it makes the assumption, that if it is not `playerOne` it **ALWAYS** must be `playerTwo` which is not the case in your code example. If it is `playerThree`, then nothing happens.

Comment: Your indexes are wrong. There's an off-by-one problem here compared to the original code.

Comment: Agreed! Made a correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you rewrite it to be something along the lines of

```
if (player == "playerOne") {
  p = playerOne
} else if (player =="playerTwo") {
  p = playerTwo
}
Object.assign(p, fighters[id - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop might be helpful:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  if (id == i && player == "playerOne") {
    Object.assign(playerOne, fighters[id - 1]);
  } else if (id == i && player == "playerTwo") {
    Object.assign(playerTwo, fighters[id - 1]);
  }
}
```